# Where can I download the ACER Aspire X1300 Chipset driver for Windows 7 x32?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, acer-aspire

Where can I download the ACER the Aspire X1300 Chipset driver for Windows 7 x32? On the [Acer website it only has x64 downloads](http://www.acer.ca/ac/en/CA/content/drivers).

What is the consequence if I use the Vista x64 instead?

Comment: How much RAM do you have in this machine?

Comment: I've checked out the link you have mentioned and it seems to have what you are looking for. Cn you be more specific ?

Comment: @Alain Pannetier - Good point, my bad: I forgot to mention specifically which drier I meant! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Official Acer FTP site**

I've checked out the link you have mentioned and it seems to have what you are looking for.
Cn you be more specific ?

**Official Europe Acer FTP site**

You can try the [Acer **Europe *FTP*** download Center](http://support.acer-euro.com/drivers/ftp/ftp.html) instead. It does not have have the Aspire X 1300 but has the Vista 32bits Aspire X1200 or X1700.

I'd look whether any of the devices in these models (or indeed other models) are the same as the ones on the X1300.

- Vista **64** bits drivers won't work on Vista or W7 32 bits.
- Vista **32** bits drivers are likely to work on W7 32 bits.

**Non Official FTP**

Otherwise you can always use an FTP indexer (same as google but for ftp files).

Such as [NAPALM](http://www.searchftps.com/indexer/search.aspx).  Just enter your device name (e.g. nVidia 8200).